# After I upload a file to library its name converted to dashes

Tags: images, uploads, attachments

I've a problem when I upload Attachment file (any extension) with Arabic name, for example اسم الصورة.jpg, It renamed to -------------.jpg ! I've plugins to crop the uploaded Image, I tried to deactivate that plugin but the problem still ..
plugins are :

```
Force Regenerate Thumbnails

Image Regenerate & Select Crop
```

[image]

Comment: Ask your host if there is anything server or filesystem related that could do this.

Comment: no problem with host, everything is ok there

Comment: Is it possible that the server doest not support foreign languages characters? Try uploading something named sample.jpg.

Comment: if the file name in English or numbers it's ok, but the problem only with Arabic characters. @gdaniel